# How I need to use isMultiple(of: ) to print even indexed characters?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

So my task is to only print even indexed characters using for-in loop.

> Create a for-in loop that will loop through alphabet. Inside the loop, print every other letter by continuing to the next iteration if you are on a letter you do not wish to print. (Hint: You can use the isMultiple(of:) method on Int to only print even indexed characters).

Here's my code:

```
let alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

for letter in alphabet {
    if letter == "F" { // letter I wish not to print
        continue
    }

    // How do I need to use isMultiple(of: ) method?

    print(letter)
}
```

Comment: Well you don't "_need_" to use it.

Comment: I know) But I am interested in using it.

Comment: To get *indexed characters* use `for (index, letter) in alphabet.enumerated()`, or – better – [`stride`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride) the characters by 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it.

```
let alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

for (index, letter) in alphabets.enumerated() {
    if index.isMultiple(of: 2) {
        continue
    }
    print(letter)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The *swifty* way is `enumerated()`– to get *indexed characters* – in conjunction with a `where` clause.

The `where` clause skips the current iteration if the condition is `false`.

```
let alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
for (index, letter) in alphabet.enumerated() where index.isMultiple(of: 2) {
   print(letter)
}
```

This prints "A C E ..."

Comment: Thanks! But what means 'where'?

Comment: The meaning of `where` is *and if* applied to each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that we need to put 'print' statement inside 'if' statement, because it will print even indexes (what task says).

```
let alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

for (index, letter) in alphabet.enumerated() {
    if letter == "F" {
        continue
    }
    if index.isMultiple(of: 2) {
        print(letter)
    }
}
```

But if we put 'continue' inside if statement, we will skip even indexes. So the odd ones will be printed.
Am I right?

Comment: Yep. continue skips the rest of the code in the current iteration, and moves onto the next.